# How do I upload files in stoarge and in my database using Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file-upload

Something strange is happening. I think I had it working at some point, but now for some reason it is not. I'm trying to upload resume (Word doc) and video files and store them into my database at the same time. My store method works, but my update method is acting weird. The resume file is being placed in storage/app/public/resumes, but if the user already has a resume in his profile and wants to Update his profile with a new resume, it's not updating properly.

The way I have it set up is, 2 tables job_seeker_profiles with resume_id column and resumes table with file column that stores the file path and I created a relationship between the 2 tables. Also note that I set it up where if they upload a new resume, the old resume will be deleted.

This is what's happening. After I click "Update" button, if id column is 10 in resumes table, it's inserting 11 in resume_id column in job_seeker_profiles table. It's always a difference of 1 no matter what I do. I tried storing the id in a variable and insert $var-1 and nothing works no matter what I try. It seems like no matter what I try
those 2 id values cannot be the same.
I'm getting this error:

```
Trying to get property 'file' of non-object
```

because I'm trying to display the resume but the id's aren't the same.
Here is my code:

AdminJobSeekerProfileController.php:

```
public function store(JobSeekerProfileCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $user = Auth::user();

        if($file = $request->file('resume_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('resumes', $name);

            $resume = Resume::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['resume_id'] = $resume->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_one_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_one_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_two_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_two_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_three_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_three_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        $user->jobSeekerProfile()->create($input);

        Alert::success('Your Profile has been created successfully!')->autoclose(5000);

        return redirect('/admin/job-seeker/profile');
    }
```

```
public function update(JobSeekerProfileCreateRequest $request)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        $input = $request->only([
            'user_id',
            'photo_id',
            'video_one_id',
            'video_two_id',
            'video_three_id',
            'date_of_birth',
            'full_or_part_time',
            'experience',
            'additional_skills',
            ]);

        if($file = $request->file('resume_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('resumes', $name);

            $resume = Resume::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $resumeId = DB::table('resumes')->latest('id')->first();

            $user->jobSeekerProfile()->update(['resume_id' => $resumeId->id]);

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_one_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_one_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_two_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_two_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_three_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_three_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        // delete the users first video from the storage/app/public/videos folder and in the videos table
        $oldVideo1 = Video::all()->where('id', $user->jobSeekerProfile()->first()->video_one_id);

        if($oldVideo1->first() != null) {
            Storage::delete('/videos/'.$oldVideo1->first()->file);
            $oldVideo1->first()->delete();
        }

        // delete the users second video from the storage/app/public/videos folder and in the videos table
        $oldVideo2 = Video::all()->where('id', $user->jobSeekerProfile()->first()->video_two_id);

        if($oldVideo2->first() != null) {
            Storage::delete('/videos/'.$oldVideo2->first()->file);
            $oldVideo2->first()->delete();
        }

        // delete the users third video from the storage/app/public/videos folder and in the videos table
        $oldVideo3 = Video::all()->where('id', $user->jobSeekerProfile()->first()->video_three_id);

        if($oldVideo3->first() != null) {
            Storage::delete('/videos/'.$oldVideo3->first()->file);
            $oldVideo3->first()->delete();
        }

        // delete the users resume from the storage/app/public/resumes folder and in the resumes table
        $oldResume = Resume::all()->where('id', $user->jobSeekerProfile()->first()->resume_id);
        Storage::delete('/resumes/'.$oldResume->first()->file);
        $oldResume->first()->delete();


        $user->jobSeekerProfile()->update($input);

        // Sweet Alert
        Alert::success('Your Profile has been updated successfully!')->autoclose(5000);

        return redirect('/admin/job-seeker/profile');
    }
```

JobSeekerProfile.php model:

```
public function resume(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Resume');

    }
```

Resume.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resume extends Model
{

    protected $uploads = '';

    protected $fillable = ['file'];

    //create an accessor
    public function getFileAttribute($resume){

        return $this->uploads . $resume;

    }

    public function jobSeekerProfile(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\JobSeekerProfile');

    }

}
```

Comment: you are updating first and then deleting the file using the updated data. so the new updated file gets deleted instead of the old one and as the new data gets deleted you are facing error like trying to get property of non object.

Comment: How can I fix this? Hmm. I see where the error is in these 3 lines of code:
```        $oldResume = Resume::all()->where('id', $user->jobSeekerProfile()->first()->resume_id);
        Storage::delete('/resumes/'.$oldResume->first()->file);
        $oldResume->first()->delete();
```

Comment: delete old files first and then update. this will solve your issue.

Comment: Yes this is what I did, thank you!